# WLAN (wifionice) @ deutsche Bahn not working with docker installed

Tags: networking, docker, captive-portal

I was travelling by train with german railroad company "deutsche Bahn" and wanted to use their provided onboard wlan. I connected to their wlan, and wanted to visit a website in my browser, but redirection to their captive portal was not working.

I was also connected with my mobile and everything was working as it should, so I assume that there was no problem with their wlan.

I have a HP elitebook 840G5 running Manjaro Linux Gnome edition and docker installed.

I was wondering how to figure out what was wrong and how to solve this issue?

After investigating a bit I found the solution by myself, but I wanted to share my solution to help others running into the same problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue occured because the wlan of the ICE train was using the same subnet as docker on my machine: `172.18.x.x`.

This is also outlined [here](https://develovers.de/2018/07/wifionice-und-docker/) (unfortunately just in german)

I fixed this, defining a new default IP range for docker, creating `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "default-address-pools":
    [
        {"base":"172.19.0.0/16","size":24}
    ]
}
```

After this I restarted the docker daemon: `sudo systemctl restart docker.service`.

Afterwards I was able to access the internet (with proper redirection to captive portal).

Comment: What is an ice train, is it a deutsche Bahn? Sorry my German sucks. I think Bhan = train. Deutsche = German. Ice = ?

Comment: I allway wondered which private networks should be used when, and how to minimise conflict. I also wondered why docker can not use `127.0.0.0/8` (not 172).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I think it's [this service](https://www.bahn.com/en/view/trains/on-board-service/ice-portal.shtml).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor For now (`*`) 127.0.0.0/8 falls under the [localnet](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.19#n1145) rules: non routable by default on linux (or any sane router). (`*`) Some people would like this to change ([netdev 0x13](https://www.files.netdevconf.org/f/1de5f5ffa5b64cf2b591/))

Comment: @A.B but docker **is** on the same node.

Comment: @A.B interesting article. I have thought the same about some of these addresses (some I did not know about). We need to keep back some of the `127.0.0.0/8`, but not the full `2^24`. I wonder how many people use. I use about 5, on my small desktop.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor ICE is for "inter city express"

Answer (score 3):

Changing the config like @Mutzmann suggested did not have any effect, I guess because the **Network Bridge created by docker already existed**.

To list all network bridges:

```
$ ip addr
```

Ip ranges which are affected;
`172.16.255.255`, `172.17.255.255`, `172.18.255.255` - The latter did it for me.

Deleting the network occupying the same ip-range(mostly 172.18.255.255) using the name from `ìp addr` with;

```
$ sudo ip link delete <name>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted `daemon.json` answer, i also had to run

```
docker network prune
```

I believe this achieves the same as manually deleting the networks, but is probably safer.