# Connecting to WIFIonICE fails because a secondary connection of the base connection failed

Tags: networking, docker, captive-portal

I am travelling with [Deutsche Bahn](https://www.bahn.de/). I use a Debian Testing with Docker installed. I am aware of the necessary workarounds, e.g. described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671930/318363) or [here](https://plasisent.org/2020/db-wifi-on-ice-docker/), and applied them.

Unfortunately connecting to WIFIonICE does not work. If I try to connect with `nmcli` I get the following error message:

```bash
$ LANG= nmcli connection up WIFIonICE
Error: Connection activation failed: A secondary connection of the base connection failed
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=405cf3fb-6465-46e4-9205-8b0447b80f59 + NM_DEVICE=wlp3s0' to get more details.
```

The same problem, but in German:

```bash
$ nmcli connection up WIFIonICE
Fehler: Aktivierung der Verbindung ist gescheitert: Eine Zweitverbindung der Basisverbindung schlug fehl
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=405cf3fb-6465-46e4-9205-8b0447b80f59 + NM_DEVICE=wlp3s0' to get more details.
```

Unfortunately, the suggested `journalctl` command was not helpful in this occassion. It returned nothing.

```bash
$ journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=405cf3fb-6465-46e4-9205-8b0447b80f59 + NM_DEVICE=wlp3s0
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
-- No entries --
```

Why doesn't the network connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears if a [automatic VPN connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107738/901319) is set up. Since the connection requires one to accept some Terms and Conditions before allowing network access, the VPN connection cannot come up. As a consequence the entire network connection cannot be established.

The solution was to disable the automatic VPN connection.

Regarding `journalctl` being not helpful, one must make sure to run it with root privileges. Only then some output is shown at all. Unfortunately the pager hid the warning that is quite obvious in the question.

However, even with `sudo journalctl ...` the output is not helpful. I could not find any mentions of VPN or my VPN's name.

Comment: great to hear you've solved it! Did the recommended journalctl invocation lead to this conclusion, or did you figure out through other means?

Comment: journalctl was useless here. After I exhausted all other options, I thought deeper about what a "secondary connection" could be.

Comment: cool! Would you add that to your answer? would enhance what future readers would learn from it :)

Comment: super nice, thank you! I can sadly only upvote once.